# Joomla 2.5.4 plugins does not appear on main site

Tags: joomla2.5

I install **Joomla 2.5.4 plugin System - Twitter Roll** and set basic configuration which I know but it does not appear on main site infect any plugin which I installed does not appear on front site and there is no extra option in installed plugin to define some page where to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay all i need to add

> {twitter_search}Joomla{/twitter_search}

in my articles.